# Comparing User input variable to time command in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that'll run in the background and shut my computer off when the regional time corresponds to a time I've set so that I can fix my sleep schedule.

However, I'm running into issues testing how to compare the current time to the time I've set as a variable.

I believe that it's due to the format that is returned by the `time` command and the format I entered not being the same.

I would like to enter a time in the 12-hour format and the computer shuts down at the designated time. But the `time` command returns a 24-hour format string unless paired with the `/t` switch.

This is what I currently have as test code that returns a printed line instead of shutting down my computer:

```
@echo off

set /p shutdownTime=What time would you like to shut down the computer?

:begin
set time=time /t
if "%time%" EQU "%shutdowmTime%" echo Time Confirmed
goto begin
```

I know that instead of an if statement in a loop I could probably do a for or while loop, but I'm honestly trying to keep it as simple as I can for my nocturnal smooth brain that woke up about 3 hours ago.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For starters, the `time /T` command is not executing and being assigned to the variable named time. Secondly there is already a system variable named time. That variable is region and country dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`time /t`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
echo %var%
pause
```

will output 12hr time

```
@echo off 
:resettime
echo make sure to Use caps for AM/PM and no spaces
set /p stime=What time would you like me to shutdown your computer?[example 03:45(AM/PM)]:
cls 
echo your computer will shutdown at %stime%
:R
set /p p=would you like to change this time [y/n]: 
if %p%==y goto resettime
if %p%==n goto loop
if not %p%==y goto R
if not %p%==n goto R
:loop 

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`time /t`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)

set var=%var: =%

if %stime%==%var% goto endloop

goto loop 

:endloop
shutdown /s
:a
set /p prompt=Would you like to abort shutdown [y/n]:
if %prompt%==y goto s
if not %prompt%==y goto a
:s 
shutdown /a
```

I also quickly made the program described in your question. Its a bit buggy but it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate this and will definitely be taking advantage of it next semester!